# Safe to start CA-server past its tombstone?

Tags: certificate-authority, tombstones

I have a CA-server that has been offline for 185 days, so past the tombstone period of 180 days.
Is it safe to start it up, or is there a high chance I will mess up my domain?

The only roles installed are Active Directory Certificate Services and Web Server (IIS).

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tombstone setting affects only deleted objects and domain controllers. Since your PC doesn't meet the requirements, so it is safe to start your PC without worrying about messing your AD.